# Compiling of a simple function causes Undefined symbols: "_main"

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

How do I run and execute this code? If I want an array of 10x10 for example. 
I have tried `gfortran hehe.f90 -o hehe`in terminal, but I get a error message.  My file is called hehe.f90

Error message I get is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My code is:

```
function test(n)

!input
integer :: n


!output
integer :: arraytest(n,n)


!local
integer :: i,j


arraytest=0.0d0

do i=1,n
  do j=1,n

arraytest(i,j)=i*i

end do

end do



end function test
```

Comment: Please add the error message in your post.  It will increase your chance of getting an answer (I do not use `gfortran`, but others might be able to help).

Comment: `n` is never initialized to 10. Add the declaration `integer, parameter :: n = 10` for a constant value of 10.

Comment: Also, you need to decide if you want static arrays (size is pre-defined) or allocatable arrays where the size is decided upon running your program.

Comment: allocatable, where do i put that in my program?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things I am noticing.

1. This is a function, not a program. You should begin your script with `PROGRAM <programname>`
2. After starting the program, you should add `IMPLICIT NONE` to avoid complications with interfaces and such.
3. If you want to have functions or subroutines defined in the program body - follow this example structure:

   ```
   program <programname>

   implicit none

   <programbody>

   stop

   contains

   function <functionname> (<variables>) result (<variable>)

   end function <functionname>

   subroutine <subroutinename> (<variables>)

   end subroutine (<subroutinename>)

   end program <programname>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You declare `test(n)` as a subroutine, so the absolute minimum you have to do is to call it from within the program, something like this:

```
program hehe
    implicit none
    call test(10)
contains
    subroutine test(n)
        implicit none
        .
        .
        .
    end subroutine test
end program hehe
```

But this isn't the end of your issues: While this would create a shape (10,10) array called `u` and populate it with values, it would immediately forget about it again when reaching the end of the subroutine.

If you want to keep `u`, you have to get a bit more involved:

```
program hehe
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: n = 10
    integer :: u(n, n)
    call test(n, u)
contains
    subroutine test(n, u)
        implicit none
        integer, intent(in) :: n
        integer, intent(out) :: u(n, n)
        < populate u >
    end subroutine test
end program hehe
```

Because you're still not doing anything with `u`, it is still possible that any compiler would secretly ditch the unnecessary computation of `u`, but if you, for example, print it out, it should do what you expect.

You could also use a function:

```
program hehe
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: n = 10
    integer :: u(n, n)
    u = test(n)
contains
    function test(n) result(v)
        implicit none
        integer, intent(in) :: n
        integer :: v(n, n)
        < populate v >
    end function test
end program hehe
```

(I've used `v` in the function to show that the two variable names don't have to be the same. `test(n)` will return a 2D array, and what you store that in is up to you.)

There is also an option that I want to include for completeness, but that I would discourage you from using: Procedures (both subroutines and functions) that are placed inside the `contains` section of a program, have access to the program's variables unless a new variable is explicitly declared with the same name, so this would work too:

```
program hehe
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: n = 10
    integer :: u(n, n)
    call test()
    write(*, '(10I6)') u
contains
    subroutine test()
        implicit none
        integer :: i, j  ! n and u not declared here, taken from program.
        u = reshape((/((100*i + j, i = 1, n), j = 1, n)/), (/n, n/))
    end subroutine test
end program hehe
```

The reason I don't like this is because it is a mess to understand if something goes wrong. You immediately start to wonder: "Where was `u` changed?" and you basically have to look everywhere.